# Strange behavior printing text in a Table from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to print in multiple Tables some parsed text using for loops, conditions,etc.

Let's say for page a (hardening.html), everything works fine. But for page b (boot.html), with same code (adapted for page b) it's not working. For some reason the same text is overwritten all the time.

Here is the demonstration:
(Correct)
[image: Correct!]
(Wrong -> It shows on screen all the time TEST PASSED but it's not true)
The expected value for `BOOT-5122` status is: `Set a password on GRUB bootloader to prevent altering boot configuration...` and the expected value for `BOOT-5180`is `Determine runlevel and services at startup` but I'm getting instead `TEST PASSED` all the time...why? what's wrong?
[image: Wrong]

And the code (simplified):

Hardening.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tabletest.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>
<body>
    <!--Añadimos al area principal el efecto acordeon con el texto -->
    <section class="mainArea" align="center">

    <H1><CENTER>HARDENING TESTS AND SUGGESTIONS</H1></CENTER>

            <div class="testTable" id="testTable">
                <script>
                    var testsRecovered = localStorage.getItem("tests"); 
                    var suggestionsRecovered = localStorage.getItem("suggestions");
                    var testsParsed = ["HRDN-7220", "HRDN-7230", "HRDN-7222"];
                    var suggestionsParsed = ["HRDN-7222 Harden compilers like restricting access to root user only"];


                        var body = document.getElementById('testTable');
                        var table = document.createElement('table');
                        body.appendChild(table);
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                        tr.appendChild(td2);
                        var txt = document.createTextNode('Test ID');
                        var txt2 = document.createTextNode('Status');
                        td.appendChild(txt);
                        td2.appendChild(txt2);
                        var txt4 = null;

                        for (var i = 0; i < testsParsed.length; i++) {                            
                            if(testsParsed[i].includes("HRDN")){    
                                var tr2 = document.createElement('tr');
                                table.appendChild(tr2);
                                var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                                var td4 = document.createElement('td');
                                tr2.appendChild(td3);
                                tr2.appendChild(td4);
                                for (var j = 0; j < suggestionsParsed.length; j++) {
                                    if(suggestionsParsed[j].includes(testsParsed[i])){
                                        txt4 = document.createTextNode(suggestionsParsed[j]);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        txt4 = document.createTextNode("TEST PASSED ✓");
                                    }

                                }
                                var txt3 = document.createTextNode(testsParsed[i]);

                                td3.appendChild(txt3);
                                td4.appendChild(txt4);

                                if(txt4.textContent.includes("TEST PASSED")){
                                   td4.style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold;color: green;';
                                }
                                else{
                                    td4.style.color = "orange";
                                    td4.style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold;color: orange;';   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                </script>
            </div>
    </section>

    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/t1.png" /> Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="../images/t2.png" />Reporting</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="llog.html"><img src="../images/empty.gif" />LYNIS LOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/empty.gif" />LYNIS REPORT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="../images/t3.png" />Lynis Tests</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./tests/accounting.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Accounting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/authentication.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Authentication</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/banner.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Banner</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/boot.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Boot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/crypto.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Crypto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/fileint.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />File Integrity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/firewall.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Firewall</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/hardening.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Hardening</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/kernel.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Kernel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/logging.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Logging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/mail.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Mail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/malware.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Malware</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/nameservers.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Nameservers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/networking.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Networking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/php.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />PHP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/printing.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Printing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/processes.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Processes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/shell.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Shell</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/software.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Software</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/squid.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Squid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/ssh.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />SSH</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/storage.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Storage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/time.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Time</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/tooling.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Tooling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/web.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Web</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/t2.png" />Overview</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END MENU -->

</body>
</html>
```

Boot.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tabletest.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>
<body>
    <!--Añadimos al area principal el efecto acordeon con el texto -->
    <section class="mainArea" align="center">

    <H1><CENTER>BOOT TESTS AND SUGGESTIONS</H1></CENTER>

            <div class="testTable" id="testTable">
                <script>
                    var testsRecovered = localStorage.getItem("tests"); 
                    var suggestionsRecovered = localStorage.getItem("suggestions");
                    var testsParsed = ["BOOT-5260", "BOOT-5202", "BOOT-5184", "BOOT-5180", "BOOT-5177", "BOOT-5155", "BOOT-5142", "BOOT-5139", "BOOT-5122", "BOOT-5121", "BOOT-5104"];
                    var suggestionsParsed = ["BOOT-5122 Set a password on GRUB bootloader to prevent altering boot configuration (e.g. boot in single user mode without password)", "BOOT-5180 Determine runlevel and services at startup"];
                        var body = document.getElementById('testTable');
                        var table = document.createElement('table');
                        body.appendChild(table);
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                        tr.appendChild(td2);
                        var txt = document.createTextNode('Test ID');
                        var txt2 = document.createTextNode('Status');
                        td.appendChild(txt);
                        td2.appendChild(txt2);
                        var txt4 = null;

                        for (var i = 0; i < testsParsed.length; i++) {                            
                            if(testsParsed[i].includes("BOOT")){    
                                var tr2 = document.createElement('tr');
                                table.appendChild(tr2);
                                var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                                var td4 = document.createElement('td');
                                tr2.appendChild(td3);
                                tr2.appendChild(td4);
                                for (var j = 0; j < suggestionsParsed.length; j++) {
                                    if(suggestionsParsed[j].includes(testsParsed[i])){
                                        txt4 = document.createTextNode(suggestionsParsed[j]);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        txt4 = document.createTextNode("TEST PASSED ✓");
                                    }

                                }
                                var txt3 = document.createTextNode(testsParsed[i]);

                                td3.appendChild(txt3);
                                td4.appendChild(txt4);

                                if(txt4.textContent.includes("TEST PASSED")){
                                   td4.style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold;color: green;';
                                }
                                else{
                                    td4.style.color = "orange";
                                    td4.style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold;color: orange;';   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                </script>
            </div>
    </section>

    <!-- MENU -->
    <div class="container">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/t1.png" /> Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="../images/t2.png" />Reporting</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="llog.html"><img src="../images/empty.gif" />LYNIS LOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/empty.gif" />LYNIS REPORT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="../images/t3.png" />Lynis Tests</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./tests/accounting.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Accounting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/authentication.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Authentication</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/banner.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Banner</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/boot.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Boot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/crypto.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Crypto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/fileint.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />File Integrity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/firewall.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Firewall</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/hardening.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Hardening</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/kernel.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Kernel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/logging.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Logging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/mail.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Mail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/malware.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Malware</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/nameservers.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Nameservers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/networking.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Networking</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/php.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />PHP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/printing.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Printing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/processes.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Processes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/shell.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Shell</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/software.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Software</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/squid.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Squid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/ssh.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />SSH</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/storage.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Storage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/time.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Time</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/tooling.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Tooling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./tests/web.html"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Web</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/t2.png" />Overview</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END MENU -->

</body>
</html>
```

layout.css:

```
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body {
        background-color:#bababa;
    }

    div#fileOutput{
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 960px;
        height: 800px;
        white-space: pre-line;
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    input[type="file"]{
        margin: auto;
        width: 960px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        white-space: pre-line;
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 5px;

    }


    .mainArea {
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        width: 960px;
        white-space: pre-line;
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

menu.css:

```
#nav {
    border:3px solid #3e4547;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color:#d4d5d8;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("../images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("../images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a.sub:focus {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display:block;
}
#nav a.sub:active {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

tabletest.css:

```
.testTable {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    width:100%;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
}.testTable table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.testTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
}
.testTable table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
}
.testTable table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
}.testTable tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
}.testTable tr:hover td{
    background-color:#d3e9ff;
}
.testTable td{
    vertical-align:middle;

    background-color:#aad4ff;

    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:20px;
    color:#000000;
}.testTable tr:last-child td{
    border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.testTable tr td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.testTable tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.testTable tr:first-child td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0057af), color-stop(1, #0057af) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0057af", endColorstr="#0057af");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0057af,0057af);

    background-color:#0057af;
    border:0px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.testTable tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0057af), color-stop(1, #0057af) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #0057af 5%, #0057af 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#0057af", endColorstr="#0057af");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#0057af,0057af);

    background-color:#0057af;
}
.testTable tr:first-child td:first-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.testTable tr:first-child td:last-child{
    border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your data have 2 entries, that should correspond to the passed tests? And your tests data only references one of them. And doesn't it print the opposite of the desired result? I.e isn't this comparison `if(suggestionsParsed[j].includes(testsParsed[i]))` the condition that should show `TEST PASSED ✓`? (instead of suggestionsParsed[j])

Comment: Although this is quite a bad code writing and a question, I think what he/she wants to do was the `testsParsed` are always **PASS** unless it contains an error description in `suggestionsParsed`.

Comment: @enhzflep For the second page (boot.html) we have 11 Test id's, two of them have a different state so display `TEST PASSED` all the time it's wrong. The point is...why in Hardening.html the code can detect the comparision and print different text and same code it's not working for boot.html?

Comment: @samiunn Exactly, and why it's a bad code or question? Can you help me to improve the code or the question?

Comment: Bad code because you're putting all your javascript logic in a `<script>` and I'm assuming you're still quite new to HTML/Javascript. Bad question because you're including so much of the unnecessary code pieces in your source codes in the question.

For the solution, check my answer below..

Comment: @samiunn It's just a prototype...that's why the code it's a little bit 'dirty'.
And yes, you're right, it's my first time with JavaScript but...do you have any suggestions for fix the issue?

Comment: Btw to answer why this is quite a bad question, you could check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You should always try to keep your source code succinct for the example. Only include things that might be relevant to your problem. You shouldn't include the unoffending css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Boot.html`:

```
for (var j = 0; j < suggestionsParsed.length; j++) {
    if(suggestionsParsed[j].includes(testsParsed[i])){
        txt4 = document.createTextNode(suggestionsParsed[j]);
    }
    else{
        txt4 = document.createTextNode("TEST PASSED ✓");
    }
}
```

In my test, the `BOOT-5180` returns the error description, which is quite easy to figure out why the `BOOT-5122` turns **PASSED**. It was because the order in which the `suggestionsParsed[j]` is looped. The if operation above returns true if the `suggestionsParsed` includes a code in `testsParsed`, but if it happens at the first array of the `suggestionsParsed`, the loop will still continue and the if will return `false` thereafter.

Simple easy fix was to just add a `break` in:

```
if(suggestionsParsed[j].includes(testsParsed[i])){
        txt4 = document.createTextNode(suggestionsParsed[j]);
        break;
    }
```

But most of the problems you might've been facing doing that project, could be avoided by learning some best practices in javascript coding, or new libraries such as using jQuery. Hope this helps solving your problem.